# access restrict to authenticated users only

Tags: authentication, weblogic, saml

We are developing a self registration app.

Our app allows users to register for web apps and is deployed on a weblogic 10.3.5 app server. The weblogic is connected to a local ldap system.
Once the user registeres with our app we call corporate servces to generate a user id. password activation, authentication is all handled by the corporate servcies. which also has a corporate ldap that contains all users in the company.

The approach works fine for 'new users' ie users that are not present in the corporate ldap or the local ldap: users enter their details and are issued a user id which we then copy into the local ldap once the user activates their account.

The use case we're grappling with at the moment is how to handle 'existing' users that wish to register. These are users that are currently in the corporate ldap and wish to 'register' with our applications. They get rejected during the normal registration process as they already exist in the coroporate ldap.

What i'd like to do is force them to login (simply so they don't register on behalf of somone else) and once they're logged in simply copy their data into the local ldap.

The problem is even if they are successfully authenticated by the corporate service, they don't (yet exist) as far as the weblogic server is concerned. is there a way to obtain the user id that comes with the authentication token ?

The authentication method is SAML 1.1
The application is a standard Java EE servlet based webapp using the struts2 framework.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Within WebLogic, you can define multiple authentication providers and set them up in the order you would like the system to use. Since you are copying data over, you would have to programmatically check for the existence of the account before attempting to create it on the LDAP server.

It would be a lot simpler if you use the external LDAP server directly instead of copying the data to the internal LDAP server, letting you attempt logging the user in and creating the account only while catching the appropriate exception.